# Get page slug in Admin menu

Tags: plugins, settings-api

I'm trying to add a settings menu to my plugin, but within that menu, I can't get the 'page' slug.

I'm basically doing something like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'MyPlugin_AddAdminMenus' );
function MyPlugin_AddAdminMenus()
{
    add_menu_page('General settings', 'MyPlugin', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-General', 'render_generic_settings_page');
    add_submenu_page('my-plugin', 'General settings', 'General settings', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-General');
    add_submenu_page('my-plugin', 'Lead capturing', 'Lead capturing', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-SubPage1', 'render_generic_settings_page');
    add_submenu_page('my-plugin', 'Toggle features', 'Toggle features', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-SubPage2', 'render_generic_settings_page');
}


function render_generic_settings_page()
{
    ?>
    <form action='options.php' method='post'>

        <h1><?php echo $GLOBALS['title']; ?></h1>

        <?php
        settings_fields( 'my-plugin' );
        do_settings_sections( '.........' ); //I need 'my-plugin-SubPage1' or 'my-plugin-SubPage2' or 'my-plugin-General'.
        submit_button();
        ?>

    </form>
    <?php
}
```

I need to pass the page slug to `do_settings_sections()`, but I can't seem to get the current page slug.

I tried:

```
global $wp_the_query;
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->get('page'); //Both 'page' and 'paged'.
$wp_the_query->get('page'); //Both 'page' and 'paged'.
get_query_var('page');

global $post;
$post->post_name;

global $pagenow;
global $post_type;

get_current_screen()->id
get_current_screen()->base
get_current_screen()->parent_base
get_current_screen()->parent_file
get_current_screen()->post_type
get_current_screen()->title
get_current_screen()->taxonomy
```

The closest I've found is `get_current_screen()->id`, which returns:
`myplugin_page_my-plugin-SubPage1`

This seems to be my root page's name (from `add_menu_page()`), plus '*page*', and then my sub-page's page.

For the present, I'm just stripping `myplugin_page_` off of `get_current_screen()->id`, but I must be missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

A fast and easy solution is to fetch the slug with `$_GET['page']`. Don't forget to do some safety checks on the query after getting it.

Also, while i'm on it, to make the submenu items show up below your top level you need to change the first property of `add_submenu_page` to your top level slug.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'MyPlugin_AddAdminMenus' );
function MyPlugin_AddAdminMenus()
{
    add_menu_page('General settings', 'MyPlugin', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-General', 'render_generic_settings_page');

    add_submenu_page('my-plugin-General', 'General settings', 'General settings', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-General');
    add_submenu_page('my-plugin-General', 'Lead capturing', 'Lead capturing', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-SubPage1', 'render_generic_settings_page');
    add_submenu_page('my-plugin-General', 'Toggle features', 'Toggle features', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-SubPage2', 'render_generic_settings_page');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for both of those tips!

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck!